# Regional font in J2ME Lwuit

Tags: java, fonts, java-me, lwuit

Am developing a j2me-lwuit app in which i need to show some information in Indian Regional langauges such as (Gujrati, Marathi, Telugu).

My app works find for some of Nokia S40 devices.
but on some mobiles it shows the square blocks.

I have tried below thing which is not working for me.
1) Added regionalFont.TTF file in Lwuit theme and applied it to components like Label, Textarea.

I have used UTF-8 encoding which is correct I guess.

Please guide me on this.

Thanks
Nilesh

Answer (score 0):

You must add the font to the theme and inside the font...in the down box, you must insert all the characters that you are going to use. With accents and every sign of punctuation.

If any of them aren't there, they will show empty squares.